# How can I mock an imported dependency with express?

Tags: node.js, firebase, unit-testing, express, stripe-payments

I am unit-testing an express function. The express function uses an import which I want to mock (stripe). How can I mock an import while using express function? The issue is that it is a global import, if I could somehow make this an argument of the express function my problem would be solved.

**express code (exported to the test file as firebase_functions.subscribe)**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.client_id);

module.exports = async function( request, response ) {
  if( !request.query.id_token ) {
    response.status(400).json({message: 'id_token has not been provided'});
    return;
  }

  await admin.auth()
  .verifyIdToken( request.query.id_token )
  .then( id_token => {
    // pseudo-code: something is done with e.g. 
    const message = await stripe.xxx( id_token ); // returns 'some result I got using the stripe Mock in the process'
    response.status(200).json({message});
    return;
  })
  .catch( error => {
    return response.status(401).json({message: 'You are currently not logged in as an authorised user'});
  })
}
```

**excerpt from the test-code**

```
describe('subscribe( request, response)', () => {
  it( 'should redirect an user to an url for stripe subscriptions', async() => {
    // arrange
    const response = new ResponseSpy();
    const id_token = await get_id_token();
    const request = { query: { id_token }};
    // act
    await firebase_functions.subscribe( request, response );
    // assert
    assert.deepStrictEqual( result.json, {message: 'some result I got using the stripe Mock in the process'} );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `firebase-functions`, you'd better use `firebase-functions-test` package to test these cloud functions.

In order to mock standalone function `stripe`, you need [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) package. For more info, see [How to use Link Seams with CommonJS](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/).

I will use [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/) as the stub library. And, I will use [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode) of `firebase-functions-test` package to writing the unit testings.

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = admin.initializeApp();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.client_id);

module.exports = async function (request, response) {
  if (!request.query.id_token) {
    response.status(400).json({ message: 'id_token has not been provided' });
    return;
  }

  await app
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(request.query.id_token)
    .then(async (id_token) => {
      const message = await stripe.xxx(id_token);
      response.status(200).json({ message });
      return;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return response.status(401).json({ message: 'You are currently not logged in as an authorised user' });
    });
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
test.mockConfig({ stripe: { client_id: 'client_123' } });
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('66157457', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should send message', async () => {
    const authStub = { auth: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), verifyIdToken: sinon.stub().resolves('token_123') };
    const adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp').returns(authStub);
    const request = { query: { id_token: 'abc' } };
    const response = { status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), json: sinon.stub() };
    const stripeStub = { xxx: sinon.stub().resolves('fake message') };
    const stripeFactory = sinon.stub().returns(stripeStub);
    const subscribe = proxyquire('./', {
      stripe: stripeFactory,
    });
    await subscribe(request, response);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(adminInitStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(stripeFactory, 'client_123');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(authStub.auth);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(authStub.verifyIdToken, 'abc');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(stripeStub.xxx, 'token_123');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(response.status, 200);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(response.json, { message: 'fake message' });
    test.cleanup();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  66157457
    ✓ should send message (145ms)


  1 passing (148ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   76.92 |       50 |   66.67 |   76.92 |                   
 index.js |   76.92 |       50 |   66.67 |   76.92 | 8-9,21            
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```